# Why did they invent Sanskrit as Veda language not any other script?

Tags: vedas, mantras, sanskrit

I've a doubt since long time, I thought this is the best place to ask.

- How did Sanskrit has become main language in ancient times?
- Why did they choose Sanskrit as Veda language?
- Does those Veda hymns have any effect if they are uttered in other languages like English ( I mean when they are translated) because all mantras are vibration related and vibrations are caused due to proper pronunciation of mantras. Does this have any relation to Sanskrit language?

Please clear my doubts.

Comment: [How important is Sanskrit?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2268/how-important-is-sanskrit) may help you.

Comment: Do you mean why Sanskrit language uses Devanagari Lipi?

Comment: This has some explanation https://yamalesha.blogspot.com/2019/08/the-concept-of-mantras-i.html?m=1