# Which are the books to be read for Spiritual and Physical pleasure?

Tags: scripture, book-recommendation, kama

can any one suggest the books to be read for Spiritual and Physical pleasure?

I have been in a dilema thought of reading **Kamasutra** but then a thought comes it is sin.

We all know gathering knowlede is good however it should not be put to wrong use.

Thanks.

Comment: Kama Sutra is not scripture. Simply because the title has the word sutra in it does not make it scripture. It is adharma, not dharma. Try and use common sense.

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan i have reframed my question

Comment: @mano - 
I don't think there is a seprate list of books for spiritual pleasure , We can listen to mantras , sing Bhajans , aarties for that .So We will get Spiritual pleasure by reading all the scriptures and not by reading few selected one's ,as they are written for that purpose only.

Comment: @mano - There are innumerable stories in Hindu scriptures like Mahabharata , Ramayana ,various puranas etc.We get lot's of Spiritual pleasure (good feeling) by reading those. We can read various  books on YOGA , Meditation etc for physical well being as well.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda being a high rep user, people will consider your advice more seriously. You are being too judgemental about certain literature just because it doesn't suit your taste. As "Kamasutra" is about certain physicality, shouldn't make it *adhArmik*. Then any "cooking book" also becomes *adhArmik*, as it satisfies taste buds. To mano, your Q is good. Just because something is sinful shouldn't stop you from doing it if your conscience allows it. Similarly, just because something is divine shouldn't be done if your conscience isn't interested in it. Read what you want with stable mind.

Comment: @iammilind Yes so its the game of the mind, if we read but having stable mind wont affect until and unless the knowledge is used for the wrong purpose however a Grihastha can read and practice within his boundaries i.e his wife only(Dharmic way of doing Karma).
Thanks

Comment: @sv. I have updated the Q

Comment: @iammilind have you read Kamasutra? It doesn't say anything about Supreme Brahman or Moksha or it doesn't have any teachings of Dharma. So, why do you have soft corner for Kamasutra? Those who are interested in "Bhoga" can enjoy it. But Spiritual aspirants avoid it. It's simple. Adharma varies with person's temperament. A Spiritual Aspirant tries to slay his Indriyas, so they must avoid such literature to ease their process. All may not have stern mind. It's the same thing like 'why some saints hate women for no reason' though we shouldn't hate them. Swamiji said from Spiritual point of view.

Comment: @TheDestroyer So finally what i see is Spiritual pleasure is more heavier then physical and is permanent. I totally agree a spiritual seeker should not see or watch such stuff but can we call it Adharma?

Comment: @TheD, I haven't read Kamasutra fully. But it's about respecting others' beliefs. Many ppl find Kamasutra good & even see divinity in such literature. That doesn't give right to us to vilify them. If Gita talks about Moksha, then it doesn't make that as supreme. By this we are asserting everyone to adapt "1 solution for all problems". That's wrong. Ppl have different natures & they see divinity in different aspects of material world. Among all indriya-s, "sex" is the only 1 which can be restricted for long enough time, & hence targeted for suppression. An *adharma* for X may be *dharma* for Y.

Comment: @iammilind I read Kamasutra but didn't find any useful stuff in that. Yeah. We should respect others beliefs but this site is for Spirituality. It agains depends on person's temperament to choose Moksha or other thing as Supreme (like Purvamimasa School. For them attaining Indrahood is highest position). As now many people are Vedantins, People say Moksha is Supreme and literature which talks about it as Supreme. Even personally, i find logically Moksha is Supreme Bliss and also there's no point of return.

Comment: @iammilind Yes. You can find divinity through Sex also. That's what Aghoras or Vaamacharis do. [Maithuna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maithuna) is part of "5 Ms" of Shaivism and Shaktism, mostly Tantra. But due to "inherent nature of Sex", people or 99% of Aghoras fall prey to senses coming back to "Bhoga". So, Acharyas suggest not to see divinty through sex unless one is highly self restraint. For most of cases, we can attack "sex" and term it as bad (Bhoga sex). Rishis and Acharyas said this with their self knowledge.

Comment: @mano "What you sow is what you reap" this is called law of  Karma. Rishis differentiated Dharma and Adharma, so that we follow only Dharma  and we get good results in return. But Moksha is beyond Dharma and Adharma. We get unfriendly results if we watch such stuff. Dharma and Adharma varies with time but truth is always same. Yes. Physical pleasure is ephemeral but Moskha is infinite bliss. Brahman is "Satchidanandaroopa". Sat = true or existing chid = expression or knowledge Ananda = Bliss. Supreme Brahma is ever existing Happiness and Moksha is becoming or mingling with him.

Comment: In your edit, I don't understand what you mean by "Physical pleasure"? There is already a question [How to read Hindu Scriptures](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15693/2995).

Comment: @iammilind I would ask you to please read the forum rules. This forum is about the Hindu religion, not Indian culture in general. Questions should be about religious topics. There are many aspects to Indian culture that do not fall under religious topics and are not suited for this forum.

Comment: @Swamiji, May be you can put a meta topic if "indian culture" is not part of "Hinduism", so that everyone are aware of it. But even in that case, if "Kamasutra" is falling outside forum rules then it should be conveyed like that. Calling it *Adharma* has a larger & totally different meaning. I haven't talked against closing this question, but against "vilifying" certain aspect of life as *adharma*. I wouldn't have commented this to anyone else. You have been part of this site for long time with high reputation. All respect you. If you will also start passing judgements, then what's difference?

Comment: @iammilind I think no one should read Kamasutra because of two reasons. First, Kamasutra encourages Kama, which is wrong. Second, it increases the desire for masturbation and sex, which is undesirable.