# What mantras for pursuing kama/artha life?

Tags: shiva, devi, shakti, kama, artha

I was taught gayatri mantra at a young age and I do it daily as it helps a lot with my daily meditation

In hinduism, moksha is the ultimate goal. But also there is the role of artha, kama, and Dharma. I was wondering what mantras I should/could add to my daily practice to pursue a more stable career/dating life? More specifically I have specific life goals to achieve through charity work in my lifetime that I can only achieve with a stable marriage and successful career

I was taught Mahamrityunajay mantra (om tryambakam yajamahe etc.)

And mahadevi mantras as well (Sarva Mangala Mangalye Shive Sarvaartha Saadhike Sharanye Trayambake Gauri Narayani Namostute etc.)

I am assuming that mahamrityunjaya is for protection and the mahadevi mantra would be for wealth/prosperity? so they would both be beneficial for this goal?

Comment: Ur Q seems duplicate of an unanswered Q https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/23407/12304

Comment: @YDS that question is seeking for the scriptures which describe Artha and Kama whereas this question is asking about chanting mantras for the fulfillment of the stage of life.