# Procedure & rules to be followed while listening or narrating puranas?

Tags: puranas

I want to ask about procedure and  the rules to be followed while listening or narrating the puranas and Who can read the Puranas?

Comment: [How to read Hindu Scriptures](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15693/how-to-read-hindu-scriptures) may help you.

Answer (score 7):

The general rules the listener and narrator should have to follow , while listening or  narrating the  puranas are given **Shreemad Bhagvat Maha Purana**  and in **Shiva-MahaPurana (Chapter 7 –Description of worship of the book and the orator) .**

Before starting reading or narrating puranas one should do a **Sankalpa** , Its highlighted that one should listen or narrate the puranas with pure and deep devotion .Only with  **pure devotion and pure love towards god** gives respective outcome of listening or narrating of puranas.

---

Some of the  shlokas describing procedure and the rules to be followed while listening or narrating from **Shiva-Maha purana chapter 7**

> आसमाप्तपुराणं हि समुपोष्य सुशक्तिमान 
>  
>     श्रुणुयाद्भक्तित: शुद्ध:पुराणं शैवमुत्तमं॥६॥
>
> Or a listener **who is quite healthy ,should keep fast till the end of
>   the Katha** ,getting purified. He should listened to the story of
>   Shiva-Purana with devotion.One should listen to the katha with comfort
>   consuming Ghee or Milk
>
> ---
>
> घृतपानं पय: पानं कृत्वा वा श्रुणुयात्सुखं 
>  
>     फ़लाहारेण वा श्राव्यमेकभुक्तं न वा हि तत्॥७॥
>
> The orator or speaker should consume **fruit or take food  once in a
>   day** and recite the Shiva-Purana.
>
> ---
>
> पलाण्डु लशुनं हिङ्गु गृञ्जनं मादकं हि तत्:
>  
>     वस्तुन्यामिषसंज्ञानि वर्जयेदय: कथाव्रती॥१२॥
>
> **Onion ,Garlic ,asafetida ,carrots** and other **intoxicating Drinks** should **not** be consumed by the person listening to the
>   katha daily.
>
> ---
>
> गृहस्थच्श्रेद्भ् वेच्छोता कर्तव्यस्तेन
>   धीमता
>  होम: शुद्धेन हविषाकर्मणस्तस्य शान्तये॥३६॥
>
> In case the listener is a House-Holder , then the wise people should  **perform homa** with pure ghee of cow **for Shanti of Katha.**
>
> ---
>
> Some of the  shlokas describing ,Procedure and the rules to be followed while listening or narrating Shreemad Bhagvat Purana , which are given in **Shreemad Bhagvat purana (Mahatmya or glory part) which is originally from Skanda purana vaishnava kanada , bhagvat mahatmya**
>
> एषोsप्यत्युत्तम: पक्ष: सप्ताहो बहुसंमत:
>   Experts say that its best to **read Shreemad Bhagvat purana in 7 days.**
>
> ---
>
> पुस्तकं च गुरुंचैव पुजयित्वोपचारत:
>   One should **pray** and honour **Purana** book and **Guru Ved-Vyasa** everyday before reading or listening.
>
> ---
>
> पयसा वा हविष्येण मौनं भोजनमाचरेत
>  
>     ब्रह्मचर्यमध: सुप्तिं क्रोधलोभदिवर्जनं  ॥४४॥
>     One should only **consume milk** during those days and **maintain celibacy** , one should sleep on floor without bed ,and must **keep one-self away from anger and lust.**
>
> ---
>
> कथान्ते कीर्तनं नित्यं समप्तौ जागरं चरेत 
>  
>     ब्रह्मणान् भोजयित्वा तु दक्षिणाभि: प्रतोषयेत ॥४५॥
>  
>   After compilation of story , each day **kirtan** should be performed and at the end of reading or listening of purana. **Jagaran** (not sleeping whole night while singing songs of god) has to be observed.