# Learning the Vedas and other scriptures

Tags: vedas, philosophy, upanishads

I would like to read and learn our Hindu scriptures. I do not know where to start at. As I understand the primary source of all knowledge is from the Vedas. I have a very basic understanding of Sanskrit which I am sure will not allow me to understand the non translated versions of these scriptures but I do have a solid grip on Hindi. Any suggestions on where to start, books to read, authors, publications or other sources would be really helpful.

Comment: GitaPress Gorakhpur is the best publication for Gita, Puranas, Ramayana, etc

Comment: I see. Where do you suggest I should start? I would like to approach this in a chronological order(if such a chronology exists that is). Is there a particular book that you would recommend?

Comment: Have a look at this question and answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15693/how-to-read-hindu-scriptures