# The best and easiest way to learn the Bhagwad Geeta

Tags: vedas, mahabharata, upanishads, gita

Which is the best and easiest way to learn the Bhagwad Geeta? And other Epics, Vedas and scriptures etc, in both audiovisual forms etc.

Comment: the best way is through the original audio visual form - your guru.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good question. Please note: that **Gitas, Upanishad, and Tantra** are Rahasya Literature (Secret Literature) that was only given to eligible students by realized Gurus. So they are not meant for casual reading. They are not meant to be translated word to word. If one reads a word-to-word translation two things will happen. 1st they will lose the entire context. 2nd they will treat them as Religious commandments and become a cult. As the other member's answer says: "Please don't read cult or sectarian version". General masses were always given Aagamic Practices, Itihasas, and later Puranas through Pravachana (detailed explanation given by scholars on open platforms during various religious events to understand the concept called Tatva).

**Coming to Vedas** (the Samhitas, Brahmanas and Aranyakas). Please note the Upanishads we already covered above. "Vedas" is not a single book or a volume of books. There are 4 Vedas and each Veda has many branches called Shakas. At one time there were over 1180 Shakas. Today only 14 Shakas survive and not all are in practice. So, if you want to read them, that means you can only read the translated version of the Manuscripts that are kept in the Universities. Many researchers of Sanskrit tried to translate it and find its meaning. The issue is, each of them came up with their own version. Some are close and some are far apart. So, no matter what you read or which translation you read, you will end up with an OPINION and not knowledge. The only widely recognized Bhashya of Vedas by a native Scholar was Sayana. Many other western scholars like HH Wilson relied on Sayana as a basis for his comparative analysis. You and find his work on Internet Archieves.

**What to read? Whom to read?** One who has an inquisitive mind and wishes to explore has to use a Bhashya (commentary) given by Prodigies, and realized beings. The first collection of Bhashya across Upanishads + Sutras + Tantra + Bhakti + Gita was given by Child Prodigy Adi Shankaracharya over 1500 years ago. 600 to 700 years later many other Acharyas tried to give similar Bhashya influenced by Puranic literature.

**Where to read?** For Gita: IIT Kankup University has created an amazing portal for Gita with side by side collection of many translations. [Here is the link](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/)
Here is a list of all Bhashyas by Adi Shankara. You are welcome to choose other Bhashyas. [Here is the link](https://www.shankaracharya.org/)

Comment: Wow, an excellent in-depth response to my query. Thank you so much. Greatly appreciated. I look forward to gaining more wisdom from you, is there a portal where I can access your wisdom? e.g. facebook, WhatsApp, web site etc.?

Comment: So I am wondering what is the Best and easiest way to learn Hinduism, that was my main reason in asking about Gita etc.How and where does on start to learn Hinduism in an organized manner without jumping to many sites an youtube etc.

Comment: @mysticsoul108 "way to learn Hinduism" -- u may check related posts: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15693/12304 and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15424/12304 ...

Comment: @mysticsoul108 There is no real Hindu+ism with constituted set of books to learn. But I understand your question. Each person has a unique Psychological Framework, with their own temperaments + mental propensities. So, "THIS CULTURE" has a diverse set of Views/approaches, which are called Darshanas to witness. So you have to pick a view that's suitable for you. Here are 3 things you have to understand before you explore. 1st what these views are, 2nd get some fundamental vocabulary, 3rd if you have a busy lifestyle to explore, I can suggest a book. (pls open a question, comment space is small)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. yes, please suggest A or more books. I wish to embark on this journey in a systematic and organized manner to get a good understanding of Hinduism, not, to teach or be a guru etc, but, to learn about it. Pranam

Comment: @mysticsoul108 If book is what helps you then, the all encompassing book that in my journey has been an amazing all-in-one is “Vasistha’s Yoga by Swami Venkatesananda”. New one is expensive. Please find a used one. If you are in United States here is a link. A soft copy (pdf) should also be online (older version). But I recommend a hard copy book. Good luck. Link https://www.abebooks.com/Vasisthas-Yoga-Venkatesananda-State-University-New/31074439021/bd?cm_mmc=ggl-_-US_Shopp_Trade-_-product_id=COM9780791413647USED-_-keyword=&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIvvH2zsCA9QIVAntvBB3OewNAEAQYBCABEgIBu_D_BwE

Comment: Thanks so much for the prompt response. I found the book, Vasistha’s Yoga by Swami Venkatesananda, that you suggested and I will study this in the coming days. Shall let you know when finished, so you can suggest more books, or feel free to suggest now so I can get those as well. Pranam

Comment: @mysticsoul108 happy to see just amazing initiative.  first chapter of the book introductory with names but it will get better and straightforward. best wishes.

Comment: Please let me know of any other books, I'll order these so I get them in time. Though, I intend on reading the Speed Reading and Learning book first. There are too many books to read and a lot to learn, not enough time in one life span!!